# Inner-loop behavior of a parallelized structure using R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, lapply, multicore, doparallel

I want to understand how my parallelization is working when there is a for-loop structure inside of the structure that I am parallelizing.

I have a routine called `reg_simulation(),` which generated 100 estimations (`nrep=100`) of linear regression, each of those using a different seed (`seed <- seed + i`).

Additionally, I wrapped up the `reg_simulation()` routine inside `par_wrapper()` to run it using different possible configurations of the data generating process. In particular, changing the number of observations (`obs`) and the error term variance (`sigma`). Finally,  I parallelized this structure using `pblapply`.

Using the described setup, I am using a grid of `obs = c(250, 500, 750, 1000, 2500)` and
`sigma = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8 , 1 )` meaning `5` values in each variable, leading to a 25 combinations of the two variables. **However**, I am running 100 times these 25 combinations.

**Finally, here is my question**:

My code is...

**(a)** Running in **parallel** 25 combinations but **serially** the 100 repetition inside of them.

**(b)** Running in **parallel** all the 2500 models.

If the answer is **(a)**, please let me know how you arrived at such a conclusion because I haven't been sorted out yet, and probably it might imply that I should change my code structure.

---

Some additional comments: (1) The seed declaration on each iteration is important because it allows me to recover each possible combination of the data (e.g., iteration 78 (`seed = 78`), with `sigma=0.1` and `obs=1000`) (2) I am using `pblapply` because I want to track my code simulations' progress.

---

Here the aforementioned routines:

#### `reg_simulation()`

```
reg_simulation<- function(obs = 1000,
                          sigma = 0.5,
                          nrep = 10 ,
                          seed = 0){
  #seet seed
  res <- vector("list", nrep)
  
  # Forloop
  for ( i in 1:nrep) {
    #Changing seed each iteration  
    seed <- seed + i
    #set seed
    set.seed(seed)
    #DGP
    x1 <-  rnorm(obs, 0 , sigma) 
    x2 <-  rnorm(obs, 0 , sigma) 
    y <-  1 + 0.5* x1 + 1.5 * x2 + rnorm(obs, 0 , 1) 
     #Estimate OLS
    ols <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)  
    returnlist <- list(intercept = ols$coefficients[1],
                       beta1     = ols$coefficients[2], 
                       beta2     = ols$coefficients[3],
                       seed      = seed)
    #save each iteration
    res[[i]] <- returnlist
    }
  return(res)  
}
```

#### `par_wrapper()`

```
### parallel wrapper
par_wrapper <- function(obs       =   c(250,500,750,1000,2500),
                         sigma     =   c(0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8 , 1 ) ,
                         nrep      =  10,
                         nClusters = 4)
{
  require(parallel)
  require(pbapply)
  #grid of searching space  
  prs <- expand.grid(obs = obs,
                    sigma = sigma)
  nprs <- nrow(prs) 
  rownames(prs) <- c(1:NROW(prs))
  #Print number of combinations
  print(prs)
  #### ---- PARALLEL INIT ----  ####
  ## Parallel options 
  cl <- makeCluster(nClusters)  
  ## Attaching necessary functions for internal computations
  parallel::clusterExport(cl= cl, 
                          list("reg_simulation"))
  # pblapply
  par_simres <- pblapply(cl  = cl, 
                         X   = 1:nprs,
                         FUN = function(i){ 
                           reg_simulation(
                             sigma  = prs$sigma[i],
                             obs   = prs$obs[i],
                             nrep   = nrep,
                             seed = 0)})
  ##exit cluster mode
  stopCluster(cl) 
  return(par_simres)   
}
```

#### Using the `par_wrapper()` function over a grid.

```
#using generated structure. 
res_list <- par_wrapper(
            obs       =  c(250,500,750,1000, 2500 ),
            sigma     =  c(0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8 , 1 ) ,
            nrep      =  100,
            nClusters =  4)
```

#### Console output.

```
# obs sigma
# 1   250   0.1
# 2   500   0.1
# 3   750   0.1
# 4  1000   0.1
# 5  2500   0.1
# 6   250   0.2
# 7   500   0.2
# 8   750   0.2
# 9  1000   0.2
# 10 2500   0.2
# 11  250   0.5
# 12  500   0.5
# 13  750   0.5
# 14 1000   0.5
# 15 2500   0.5
# 16  250   0.8
# 17  500   0.8
# 18  750   0.8
# 19 1000   0.8
# 20 2500   0.8
# 21  250   1.0
# 22  500   1.0
# 23  750   1.0
# 24 1000   1.0
# 25 2500   1.0

# |++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100% elapsed=01s
```

Comment: Why aren’t you using one of the benchmark package to run test cases?

Comment: To be honest, @IRTFM , I did not know that this was the way to proceed. I am very new to parallel computing, and I erroneously thought that was a matter of taking a look at the _code structure_. I will check that out. Thank you a lot for the suggestion. (Now I got why the question was downvoted.)

Comment: I'm not sure about the motivations of the downvoter. SO doesn't force downvoters to explain themselves. (It wasn't me.) It might have seemed overly complex. I did not try running the code, so I don't know if it was self contained. Now that I have run it I see it will run and I get similar output so I'll up vote it.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @IRTFM. Probably the name of my question was a bit unfortunate. However, I have reflected on my original problem, and I think it can be narrowed down to the question. _**If I have a nested loop and I parallelized the outer one, my inner loop still runs serially?**_, which I think is what is happening in the provided code. I will edit the title of the question for further references anyway. Thx!